# gammit::predict_gamm() and mgcv::predict.gam() issues predicting with random effects, predicting same values regardless of test data values

Tags: r, predict, gam, mgcv

I've been using `gammit::predict_gamm()` (which I understand uses `mgcv::predict.gam()`) to predict with GAMM/GLMM models quite happily for a while. Recently while rerunning my workflow on two training and test datasets, I've discovered an issue with regenerating predicted values, affecting reproducibility of my work.

The predicted values appear to be **equal** to the **random intercept coefficients** of each particular group (e.g. `Country_fact`), when I specify prediction with the random effect using the argument `re_form = c("s(Country_fact)")`. Hence all subject/groups appear to have the same predicted values, regardless of the variation in values across other variables in the test data. When I predict without random effects using the argument `re_form = NA`, I get predicted values that are appropriately varying. I have recreated a toy dataset which reproduces this result, reprex below (Edited following Roland's comments).

This seems to be happening regardless of model specification - GLMM or GAMM.

Is there something I have completely misunderstood about predicting with GAMMs? Could someone please test this and explain why I am getting these predicted values? Thanks very much in advance!

```
# create training data
set.seed(123)
dat <- tibble(
  Reference_fact = as.factor(rep(seq(1,10,1),5)),
  Country_fact = as.factor(rep(stri_rand_strings(10,2),5)),
  exp_A = runif(50,0,500),
  exp_B = runif(50,0,20),
  resp = exp_A^2 + 0.1*exp_B * 0.3*exp_A*exp_B + rnorm(50, 0, 10)
)

# define model specification
model_spec <- c("resp ~ 
                 s(exp_A) +
                 s(exp_B) +
                 s(Reference_fact, bs = 're') + 
                 s(Country_fact, bs = 're')"
)

# fit model (GLMM)
fit <- mgcv::gam(formula(str_replace_all(model_spec, "[\r\n]", "")),
                 method = 'REML',
                 family = 'gaussian',
                 data=dat)

# create test data
set.seed(123)
dat_pred <- tibble(
  Reference_fact = as.factor(rep(seq(1,10,1),5)),
  Country_fact = as.factor(rep(stri_rand_strings(10,2),5)), 
  exp_A = runif(50,0,500),
  exp_B = runif(50,0,20)
)

# predict with random effects
p <- gammit::predict_gamm(
  fit, 
  dat_pred, 
  re_form = c("s(Country_fact)"),
  keep_prediction_data = TRUE, 
  newdata.guaranteed = FALSE, 
  se.fit = FALSE)
```

I got this result where prediction values correspond to random effects matching output from `extract_ranef(fit)`. This does not seem expected. When predicting without random effects using the same package `gammit`, unsurprisingly I get a different set of results.

```
> p %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 50 × 5
   Reference_fact Country_fact exp_A   exp_B prediction
   <fct>          <fct>        <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 1              Hm           445.  15.1       0.0156 
 2 2              Ps           346.  12.6       0.0137 
 3 3              w2           320.  14.2      -0.00998
 4 4              Wt           497.   0.0125   -0.0117 
 5 5              YS           328.   9.51      0.0102 
 6 6              xS           354.   4.40     -0.0121 
 7 7              gZ           272.   7.60     -0.00652
 8 8              6t           297.  12.3       0.00131
 9 9              F2           145.   7.04     -0.00568
10 10             Kx            73.6  2.22      0.00514
# ℹ 40 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

> extract_ranef(fit)
# A tibble: 20 × 7
   group_var      effect    group  value    se lower_2.5 upper_97.5
   <chr>          <chr>     <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 Reference_fact Intercept 1      0.016  1.73     -3.38       3.41
 2 Reference_fact Intercept 2      0.014  1.73     -3.38       3.40
 3 Reference_fact Intercept 3     -0.01   1.73     -3.40       3.38
 4 Reference_fact Intercept 4     -0.012  1.73     -3.40       3.38
 5 Reference_fact Intercept 5      0.01   1.73     -3.38       3.40
 6 Reference_fact Intercept 6     -0.012  1.73     -3.40       3.38
 7 Reference_fact Intercept 7     -0.007  1.73     -3.40       3.38
 8 Reference_fact Intercept 8      0.001  1.73     -3.39       3.39
 9 Reference_fact Intercept 9     -0.006  1.73     -3.40       3.38
10 Reference_fact Intercept 10     0.005  1.73     -3.39       3.40
11 Country_fact   Intercept 6t     0.001  1.73     -3.39       3.39
12 Country_fact   Intercept F2    -0.006  1.73     -3.40       3.38
13 Country_fact   Intercept gZ    -0.007  1.73     -3.40       3.38
14 Country_fact   Intercept Hm     0.016  1.73     -3.38       3.41
15 Country_fact   Intercept Kx     0.005  1.73     -3.39       3.40
16 Country_fact   Intercept Ps     0.014  1.73     -3.38       3.40
17 Country_fact   Intercept w2    -0.01   1.73     -3.40       3.38
18 Country_fact   Intercept Wt    -0.012  1.73     -3.40       3.38
19 Country_fact   Intercept xS    -0.012  1.73     -3.40       3.38
20 Country_fact   Intercept YS     0.01   1.73     -3.38       3.40

# predict without random effects
p_no_re <- gammit::predict_gamm(
  fit, 
  dat_pred, 
  re_form = NA,
  keep_prediction_data = TRUE, 
  newdata.guaranteed = FALSE, 
  se.fit = FALSE) 

> p_no_re %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 50 × 5
   Reference_fact Country_fact exp_A   exp_B prediction
   <fct>          <fct>        <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 1              Hm           445.  15.1       200361.
 2 2              Ps           346.  12.6       121563.
 3 3              w2           320.  14.2       104321.
 4 4              Wt           497.   0.0125    246972.
 5 5              YS           328.   9.51      108463.
 6 6              xS           354.   4.40      126635.
 7 7              gZ           272.   7.60       74660.
 8 8              6t           297.  12.3        89526.
 9 9              F2           145.   7.04       20891.
10 10             Kx            73.6  2.22        5062.
# ℹ 40 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

When I use `mgcv::predict.gam`, I get identical results regardless of whether the `re.form` argument includes the random effect or not. These are also identical to the results from using `gammit::predict_gamm` with `re_form = NA` i.e. with no random effects.

```
pg <- mgcv::predict.gam(
  fit, 
  dat_pred, 
  re.form = c("s(Country_fact)"),
  keep_prediction_data = TRUE, 
  newdata.guaranteed = FALSE, 
  se.fit = FALSE) 

> pg %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 50 × 1
     value
     <dbl>
 1 200361.
 2 121564.
 3 104321.
 4 246972.
 5 108463.
 6 126634.
 7  74660.
 8  89526.
 9  20891.
10   5062.

pg_no_re <- mgcv::predict.gam(
  fit, 
  dat_pred, 
  re.form = ~0,
  #re.form = c("s(Country_fact)"),
  keep_prediction_data = TRUE, 
  newdata.guaranteed = FALSE, 
  se.fit = FALSE) 

> pg_no_re %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 50 × 1
     value
     <dbl>
 1 200361.
 2 121564.
 3 104321.
 4 246972.
 5 108463.
 6 126634.
 7  74660.
 8  89526.
 9  20891.
10   5062.
```

**So the question is: I would have expected the argument `re_form`/`re.form` in either package package to generate predicted values making use of Country-specific intercepts. Why is this not the case?**

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.utf8    

time zone: Australia/Sydney
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringi_1.7.12      fstcore_0.9.14      gammit_0.3.2        furrr_0.3.1         rsample_1.1.1      
 [6] ggpubr_0.6.0        cowplot_1.1.1       tmap_3.3-3          fst_0.9.8           parallelly_1.35.0  
[11] purrr_1.0.1         future_1.32.0       rlang_1.1.1         qs_0.25.5           terra_1.7-29       
[16] readr_2.1.4         targets_1.0.0       renv_0.17.3         itsadug_2.4.1       plotfunctions_1.4  
[21] mgcv_1.8-42         nlme_3.1-162        metafor_4.0-0       numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 metadat_1.2-0      
[26] Matrix_1.5-4        forestplot_3.1.1    checkmate_2.2.0     GGally_2.1.2        ggExtra_0.10.0     
[31] ggeffects_1.2.1     rasterize_0.1       rworldxtra_1.01     cleangeo_0.2-4      rgeos_0.6-2        
[36] exactextractr_0.9.1 groupdata2_2.0.2    cvms_1.3.9          VIM_6.2.2           colorspace_2.1-0   
[41] Rcpp_1.0.10         miceadds_3.16-18    mice_3.15.0         ncdf4_1.21          compareDF_2.3.5    
[46] stringr_1.5.0       R.utils_2.12.2      R.oo_1.25.0         R.methodsS3_1.8.2   rworldmap_1.3-6    
[51] here_1.0.1          RNetCDF_2.6-2       devtools_2.4.5      usethis_2.1.6       stars_0.6-1        
[56] abind_1.4-5         ncmeta_0.3.5        tidync_0.3.0        ggthemes_4.2.4      gridBase_0.4-7     
[61] raster_3.6-20       gridExtra_2.3       htmlwidgets_1.6.2   plotly_4.10.1       broom_1.0.4        
[66] rgdal_1.6-6         geojsonio_0.11.0    sf_1.0-12           maps_3.4.1          ggmap_3.0.2        
[71] maptools_1.1-6      sp_1.6-0            viridis_0.6.2       viridisLite_0.4.1   networkD3_0.4      
[76] lubridate_1.9.2     zoo_1.8-12          Hmisc_5.0-1         readxl_1.4.2        ggplot2_3.4.2      
[81] data.table_1.14.8   forecast_8.21       janitor_2.2.0       magrittr_2.0.3      tidyr_1.3.0        
[86] dplyr_1.1.2         rvest_1.0.3        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] fs_1.6.2            bitops_1.0-7        httr_1.4.5          RColorBrewer_1.1-3  profvis_0.3.7      
  [6] tools_4.3.0         backports_1.4.1     utf8_1.2.3          R6_2.5.1            lazyeval_0.2.2     
 [11] urlchecker_1.0.1    withr_2.5.0         prettyunits_1.1.1   leaflet_2.1.2       leafem_0.2.0       
 [16] cli_3.6.1           tseries_0.10-53     robustbase_0.95-1   proxy_0.4-27        foreign_0.8-84     
 [21] dichromat_2.0-0.1   sessioninfo_1.2.2   TTR_0.24.3          rstudioapi_0.14     httpcode_0.3.0     
 [26] RApiSerialize_0.1.2 generics_0.1.3      crosstalk_1.2.0     car_3.1-2           fansi_1.0.4        
 [31] gratia_0.8.1        lifecycle_1.0.3     yaml_2.3.7          snakecase_0.11.0    carData_3.0-5      
 [36] mathjaxr_1.6-0      tmaptools_3.1-1     promises_1.2.0.1    crayon_1.5.2        miniUI_0.1.1.1     
 [41] lattice_0.21-8      geojson_0.3.4       pillar_1.9.0        knitr_1.42          boot_1.3-28.1      
 [46] future.apply_1.10.0 codetools_0.2-19    glue_1.6.2          urca_1.3-3          V8_4.3.0           
 [51] remotes_2.4.2       vcd_1.4-11          vctrs_0.6.2         png_0.1-8           spam_2.9-1         
 [56] cellranger_1.1.0    gtable_0.3.3        cachem_1.0.7        xfun_0.39           mime_0.12          
 [61] timeDate_4022.108   units_0.8-2         fields_14.1         ellipsis_0.3.2      xts_0.13.1         
 [66] rprojroot_2.0.3     KernSmooth_2.23-20  rpart_4.1.19        DBI_1.1.3           nnet_7.3-18        
 [71] tidyselect_1.2.0    processx_3.8.1      compiler_4.3.0      curl_5.0.0          htmlTable_2.4.1    
 [76] geojsonsf_2.0.3     xml2_1.3.4          stringfish_0.15.7   scales_1.2.1        DEoptimR_1.0-12    
 [81] classInt_0.4-9      lmtest_0.9-40       fracdiff_1.5-2      quadprog_1.5-8      callr_3.7.3        
 [86] mvnfast_0.2.8       digest_0.6.31       rmarkdown_2.21      htmltools_0.5.5     pkgconfig_2.0.3    
 [91] jpeg_0.1-10         base64enc_0.1-3     fastmap_1.1.1       quantmod_0.4.22     shiny_1.7.4        
 [96] visibly_0.2.9       jsonlite_1.8.4      Formula_1.2-5       dotCall64_1.0-2     patchwork_1.1.2    
[101] munsell_0.5.0       leafsync_0.1.0      MASS_7.3-59         plyr_1.8.8          jqr_1.2.3          
[106] pkgbuild_1.4.0      ggrepel_0.9.3       parallel_4.3.0      listenv_0.9.0       forcats_1.0.0      
[111] splines_4.3.0       hms_1.1.3           ps_1.7.5            ranger_0.15.1       igraph_1.4.2       
[116] base64url_1.4       ggsignif_0.6.4      reshape2_1.4.4      pkgload_1.3.2       crul_1.3           
[121] XML_3.99-0.14       evaluate_0.20       mitools_2.4         RcppParallel_5.1.7  laeken_0.5.2       
[126] BiocManager_1.30.20 tzdb_0.3.0          httpuv_1.6.9        RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.3 reshape_0.8.9      
[131] lwgeom_0.2-11       xtable_1.8-4        e1071_1.7-13        rstatix_0.7.2       later_1.3.0        
[136] class_7.3-21        tibble_3.2.1        memoise_2.0.1       cluster_2.1.4       timechange_0.2.0   
[141] globals_0.16.2
```

Comment: `gammit` doesn't appear to be on CRAN. I would encourage you to use `mgcv::predict.gam`.

Comment: I have many issues with your example. First, you should simulate data, where the DV depends on the predictors. It is strange to see `poly` in a GAM. You shouldn't suppress the global intercept (smoothers are centered). You seem to be trying to predict for subjects that were not part of the training data.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.  I have updated the reprex accordingly and also added results using `mgcv::predict.gam`. However, I'm still confused as to why the predictions do not make use of subject-specific random intercepts when specified using the `re.form` argument.

Comment: `predict.gam` doesn't have a `re.form` parameter. You can only use the `exclude` parameter to exclude terms (such as random-effects smoothers).